# How to direct input and output of circuit for multifunctional 4 bit calculator

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, intel-fpga, calculator

I am trying to build a 4 bit calculator that can add subtract and multiply using a FPGA board (Altera DE2).  I have an adder/subtractor and multiplier already built and functioning but need to know how I can merge each function and give an output based on user input.
For each module:

- there will be 8 inputs (X0-X3,Y0-Y3) which represent the two numbers used for the calculations
- the adder/subtrator has an additional input to select the function (add or sub)
- The multiplier has an additional input to reset the clock that is used for the counter that shifts the bits
- the multiplier has 8 outputs (A-H) that are fed into the
- The add/sub has 7 outputs for the sign display for results that are negative
- The add/sub has 5 outputs
- all outputs except the sign display are fed into an already functioning 7 segment BCD display

How do I connect the 2 modules in a way that only the selected module gets the input and the output from only the selected module goes to BCD display?

I have included a start to my schematic with the display attached to their respective output ports.
 [image: Mulitfucntional Calulator using Quartus]

Comment: Why not use a MUX?

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami How do I implement this using a mux? On the input or the output? Please explain.

Comment: The inputs can be connected to all the blocks in parallel, no need to mux them. The outputs of the blocks must be muxed so only those of interest appear on the display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claudio Avi Chami is right, you probably don't need to select on the input - just hard wire your input to both blocks. They will both do their thing but you can just ignore the output of one of them.

Then, on the output, connect each pair of corresponding pins to the inputs of a 1-bit (2-input) mux. Connect the output of the mux to the corresponding pin on the LCD. Then connect the select line of the mux to your signal that selects which module to use. Repeat for all pairs of corresponding pins.

Shown here is the result for just 3 pairs of corresponding pins:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQysWE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Great answers!  Much appreciated as I have spent much time on building the components for this project but got stuck on how to make them work in unison.  I believe I way over thought this process as usual and this simplifies things a great deal.  Thanks again guys :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful! Don't forget to upvote or mark correct anything you appreciated.

Comment: Done!  I also uploaded the finished product just in case someone may find it useful in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's the final product with pin assignments.  It works like a charm :-)